# opencv overlaying one image over another with masking and in-painting

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-masking

I'm using OpenCV to do in-painting on a few polygons (drawn on paper, see examples).

Some legend specs:

- The green frame is there to draw the scene "borders", just there for reference.
- The blue ball is floating on the scene and when the ball hits a polygon, the scene is re-rendered with the proper masking, as if the ball is crushing the objects.

Here is a code for reference, assume that `inpaintedScene`, `transformedScene` and `outputFrame` are `cv::Mat`:

```cpp
 cv::Mat mask_image(outputFrame.size(), CV_8U, BLACK_COLOR);
 std::vector<cv::Point*> destroyedPolygons = //some sub-polygons that has been hit by the ball
 std::vector<int> destroyedPolygonsPointCount = //points count for each destroyed polygon
 for (int i = 0; i < destroyedPolygons.size(); i++)
 {
    const cv::Point* ppt[1] = { destroyedPolygons[i] };
    int npt[] = { destroyedPolygonsPointCount[i] };
    cv::fillPoly(mask_image, ppt, npt, 1, WHITE_COLOR);
 }

 // now that the mask is prepared, copy the points from the inpainted to the scene
 inpaintedScene.copyTo(transformedScene, mask_image);

 // here I have two options:
 //option 1
 outputFrame += transformedScene;

 //option 2
 transformedScene.copyTo(outputFrame, transformedScene);
```

These are the results which none of them is good for me:

Results of option no.1 (+=):

[image]

This is not good for me since I get transparency over the destroyed polygons.

Results of option no.2 (copyTo):

[image]

This is also not good because as you can see, the destroyed part of the polygon is kind a "bordered" or "framed" with black color (even though the polygon is in another color) - what can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

I've added `warpPerspective` to `transformedScene` with "nearest-neighbour" interpolation:

```
cv::warpPerspective(transformedScene, transformedScene, warpImageMat, outputFrame.size(), CV_INTER_NN);
```

where `warpImageMat` is type of `cv::Mat`

Read [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/image_processing.html?highlight=warpperspective#void%20ocl%3a%3awarpPerspective%28const%20oclMat%20&src,%20oclMat%20&dst,%20const%20Mat%20&M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags%29) more about `warpPerspective` function of OpenCV

Cheers!

Comment: It's important to note that `warpPerspective` may do interpolation where a transformed pixel falls on border between several. `CV_INTER_NN` takes the nearest neighbor while others do some interpolation on neighboring pixels and thus may end up with "unexpected" value.